# Has many through in reverse?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, join, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a set of models that's exactly like the example in railsguides:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sections
  has_many :paragraphs, through: :sections
end

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :document
  has_many :paragraphs
end

class Paragraph < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :section
end
```

They mentioned you can do this `@document.paragraphs`, which uses JOIN, but you can't go in the reverse direction... `@paragraph.document` just doesn't work. I'm aware of using `delegate`, but it still uses the same amount of queries.

Is there a way I can do this with joins() or includes() or something? What is the best way to handle an association like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, let's say you're querying for a collection of documents. Then it's important that you use `includes` to eager load the two associations you're going through:

```
@paragraphs = Paragraph.includes(:section => :document).where(:attribute => attribute)
```

And then in your view you can do this without fear of doing too many queries:

```
<% @paragraphs.each do |paragraph| %>
  <%= paragraph.section.document %>
<% end %>
```

If you wanna use `delegate` to make it even cleaner and be able to write `paragraph.document`, you'll still benefit from the eager loading.